# DisplayNameFor a Model child collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

Suppose I have

```
class Item { 
    string Name {get; set;} 
    int Type {get; set;} 
}
```

If I have my model as a collection of Items, the following compiles :

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
```

Now supppose I have changed to this

```
class MyItems {
    int Type {get; set;}
    IEnumerable<Item> Items {get; set;}
}
```

this does not compile anymore

```
@model MyItems  

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Items.Name) // NOK
```

> Error CS1061  '`IEnumerable<Item>`' does not contain a definition for
> 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' accepting a first
> argument of type '`IEnumerable<Item>`' could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Items.Name) // _M_odel, NOK
```

Why the code works in the first case when we have an `IEnumerable`, and not the second case, when we have the same `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 1):

The first one works because the model is itself of type `IEnumerable` while in latter it's the property of main model which is `IEnumerable`

The error is pretty self descriptive the `Items` property is a collection of `Item` so you need to either loop on it or select one of them like:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Items.First().Name)
```

or do like:

```
@{
     var item = model.Items.First();
 }
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.Name)
```

But the `First()` will throw exception in case the `Items` collection is null or empty.

Comment: the question is why it works in the first case. there is the same IEnumerable in the first case

Comment: we would use FirstOrDefault(), not First

Comment: so what if the model itself is IEnumerable? what is the source of error in the second case vs the first case?

Comment: and also, in the first case we have no problems if the collection is empty, in the second we have problems if the collection is empty....

Comment: @Serge it's conventions what mvc follows

Comment: yes in the second case we need to handle that ourselves from either controller end or view end

Comment: _But the First() will throw exception in case the Items collection is null or empty._ Have you tested it? Because if I'm not mistaken, `DisplayNameFor` doesn't evaluate the model, you can even pass a null instance to the View that `DisplayNameFor` will print the rigth names.

Comment: this is not a convention, but an extension method `static string DisplayNameFor<TModelItem, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModelItem>> htmlHelper,` https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Rendering/HtmlHelperDisplayNameExtensions.cs

Comment: @Magnetron it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` when the source sequence is empty, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Serge No, it won't, just tested. It can be null that will work. `DisplayNameFor` doesn't evaluate the lambda, so it will not throw. I will look for the article I saw once talking about this, if I find, I'll post here.

Comment: @Magnetron if it evaluates the expression, it should throw, if it does not evaluate, probably not.

Comment: @Serge [here it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#the--directive-1) _The DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor HTML Helper inspects the Title property referenced in the lambda expression to determine the display name. The lambda expression is inspected rather than evaluated. That means there is no access violation when model, model.Movie, or model.Movie[0] is null or empty._

Comment: @Magnetron we should admit, this is quite confusing for beginner developers. Logically it should throw exceptions, so I suppose a lot of devs would test for null etc...